# what object can read mutiple nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm not sure if I'm asking the this question correctly so forgive me in advanced if I'm not. I am fairly new to c# and coding in general. I have some code that parses an xml document (which is a bill for a customer). I have encountered an issue that I am trying to fix. A customer recently moved to another address which caused him to get billed twice. The xml that was generated came back with more than one of the same exact node. So the bill only had partial usage information and not all the information it was suppose to have. The code only checks for one node. or I'm assuming in this case it take the first node and uses that information. What I'm trying to accomplish is to modify my code to check for multiple nodes that are the same. then be able to parse all the nodes.

This is the code I have that goes through the bill list. If it comes back with a node then it parses the information from the xml.

Here is the method that checks if there is a node in the xml. if it is greater than 0 then it returns the node. I believe I need to change the object Xmlnode because it only represents a single node in the XML document. is there another object that I can use that represents multiple nodes? and how can I modify this method to check for multiple nodes and return it.

I then believe I need to go back to this portion of the code from the first snippet I posted. I think I need to put this portion of the code in a loop somehow. So that it checks all of the multiple same nodes. I'm stuck on how to do this

I can't post images since I'm new and don't have any reputation votes yet so I'm just gonna type it out so you can see what I'm talking about.This is usually what the xml look like which is normal with one DetailPage_Section node.

Again I am fairly new to this and I'm trying to understand and figure out the issue myself. So sorry if this does not make much sense.

Comment: try to use Linq to xml http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you want is already there, all you want is the `nodes` value the programmer already found for you! So all you have to do is remove some code and change your return value:

```
public static XmlNodeList GetDetailPageSectionBySa(string sa, string statementXml)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(statementXml);
    string requestSa = sa.PadLeft(9, '0');
    string xpath = String.Format("//Para[IRBILGP_SA_SAA_ID_PRINT.SERVICE.ACCOUNT.STATMENT='{0}S{1}']/..", requestSa.Substring(0, 4), requestSa.Substring(4));
    return document.SelectNodes(xpath);
    if(!SaExistInBill(requestSa, statementXml)) return null;
    var node = GetDetailPageSectionByBillPrisminfoIndex(sa, statementXml);
    if (node != null) return node;
    return null;
}
```

For all nodes to be in same bill:

```
var saDetailedPageNodes = XmlBillParser.GetDetailPageSectionBySa(requestSa, xmlBill);
if (saDetailedPageNodes.Count == 0) continue;

var customerBill = new CustomerBill();
customerBill.IsSurepay = XmlBillParser.GetSurepayFlagFromBill(document);
customerBill.ServiceAddress = XmlBillParser.GetServiceAddress(requestSa, document);
customerBill.monthName = XmlBillParser.GetnillStatementDate(requestSa, xmlBill);
customerBill.EqCurlPlanBal = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerCurrentPlanBalance(document);
customerBill.EqPymntDue = XmlBillParser.getEqualizerPaymentDue(document);

for (int i = 0; i < saDetailedPageNodes.Count; i++)
{
    // customerBill.Service needs to be an array or list
    customerBill.Service.Add(GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(requestSa, xmlBill, saDetailedPageNode[i]));
}
response.Add(customerBill);
```

Comment: OK perfect thank you. Aftter that is done do I need to do anything with the rest of the code where it does the actual parsing/ I thought I need to loop through that? I may be worng

Comment: Yes you need to show me that part though, show me where it calls this function

Comment: Okay, if all the nodes are in the same bill... How do I go about doing that.